# Removing any arbitrary vertex from a directed graph?

Tags: shortest-path, directed-graphs

I came upon this particular question which I do not understand from Jeff E. Algorithms, Chapter 9, ex. 8. https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/09-apsp.pdf

How can we remove any arbitrary vertex from a directed graph, with weighted edges that can be positive negative or zero, without changing the shortest paths distance between all other pairs of vertices, in $O(V^2)$.

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph with weighted edges; edge weights could be positive, negative, or zero.
> a)  How would we delete an arbitrary vertex $v$ from this graph, without changing the shortest-path distance between any other pair of vertices? Describe an algorithm that constructs a directed graph $G'=(V\setminus\{v\},E')$ with weighted edges, such that the shortest-path distance between any two vertices in $G'$ is equal to the shortest-path distance between the same two vertices in $G$, in $O(V2)$ time.

I have an idea would be to just consider the incoming edges $u \rightarrow v$ and outgoing edges $v \rightarrow t$ and for each $u$, add an edge $u \rightarrow t$ with the weight being the sum of the weights of $u \rightarrow v$ and $v \rightarrow t$, for all $t$. The second part builds upon the first, but now I am confused about how to go about it.

> Now suppose we have already computed all shortest-path distances in $G'$.Describe an algorithm to compute the shortest-path distances in the original graph G from v to every other vertex, and from every othervertex tov, all in $O(V^2)$ time

Is there a way to do this now that I have deleted the node?

Comment: Can you credit the original source of the quoted/copied material?  Also, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Your first part seems to be correct. Hint for the second part: note that in any shortest path $v \leadsto u$, there exists a vertex $w$ which goes right after $v$: $v \to w \leadsto u$, and the path $w \leadsto u$ must be the shortest one. If you check the proof of Floyd-Warshall, you can even solve a stronger problem: compute all pairwise distances.